# Breaking Matlab code long lines in Latex listings environment

Tags: matlab, latex, listings

I need to include Matlab code in my Latex file. I'm using the listings package with matlab-prettifier and the settings are:

```
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage[numbered, framed]{matlab-prettifier}
...
\lstset{
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily\scriptsize,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true,
}

\lstinputlisting[breaklines = true, breakatwhitespace=false]{test.m}
```

The long lines do not break, however. Any idea why this happens and how to solve it?

Edit: I discovered that if I change the class of the document from *mwbk* (current) to *article*, the lines break as desired. There should be a conflict with the class *mwbk* defined in 
http://web.mit.edu/ghudson/dev/nokrb/third/tetex/texmf/tex/latex/mwcls/mwbk.cls, but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Can't you use put some `...` in your code to manually break it at logical points?

Comment: Indeed, I prefer to avoid manual breaking.

Comment: Please help us to help you and provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces you problem,